# Oracle DB - Primary Key Auto Increment Column without Sequence

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g

I wonder if there is a way to create a table column with an primary key which is auto incremented without using a sequence.

I saw that it was working by using IDENTITY on Microsofts SQL Server and AUTO_INCREMENT on MySQL, but cannot get something that works with Oracle DB.

This is my current approach:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(   id NUMBER(6) IDENTITY,
    CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: Database version?  Identity columns were introduced in Oracle 12c.  Pre-12c, you're going to have to use a sequence.

Comment: Oh then that may be the Problem, i use the Express Version 11g. Would it work with 12c in that way i described? Thank you for the fast response :)

Comment: Pretty close... the syntax is a little different though.  Tim Hall has a good article on identity columns here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1.  In any case, your choices are to either use a sequence, or to upgrade to 12c (and I don't think 12c is available yet for express edition).  Tim Hall has a pretty good write up of auto_increment in pre-12c here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonumber-and-identity

Answer (score 1):

Identity columns in Oracle would meet your requirement, but they were introduced in Oracle Database 12c.

Since you are on Oracle Database 11g, the best approach would be to use a sequence + trigger approach.  Tim Hall has a good write up of this [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonumber-and-identity):

Excerpt:

> Create a table with a suitable primary key column and a sequence to
>   support it.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE departments (
>   ID           NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL,
>   DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(50)  NOT NULL);
>
> ALTER TABLE departments ADD (
>   CONSTRAINT dept_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID));
>
> CREATE SEQUENCE dept_seq;
> ```
>
> Create a trigger to populate the ID column if it's not specified in
>   the insert.
>
> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_bir 
> BEFORE INSERT ON departments 
> FOR EACH ROW
> WHEN (new.id IS NULL)
> BEGIN
>   SELECT dept_seq.NEXTVAL
>   INTO   :new.id
>   FROM   dual;
> END;
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
I will prefer trigger after insert as there can be an error while insertion